# Find the Set With Given Condition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $S$  be the set of$(\alpha , \beta)\in \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{\beta} }{(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} }\rightarrow 0 $ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

then $S$ is contained in

1. {$(\alpha,\beta) : \alpha>0, \beta> 0 $}
2. {$(\alpha,\beta) : \alpha>2, \beta> 2 $}
3. {$(\alpha,\beta) : \alpha+\beta> 1 $}
4. {$(\alpha,\beta) : \alpha+4\beta>1 $}

What I have tried is

Putting $ y=mx$   $  $  then we will get in the power of $x$  $ \alpha + \beta-1 $ so for convergence to  $  0 $ we yield option 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Transforming to polar coordinates reveals

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}=\lim_{r\to 0}r^{\alpha+\beta-1}\cos^\alpha(\theta)\sin^\beta(\theta)$$

Alternatively, from the AM-GM inequality we have $x^2+y^2\ge 2|x||y|$ so that

$$\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}\le \frac{x^{\alpha-1/2}y^{\beta-1/2}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: so option 3 is true here

Comment: Yes, that's correct.